TEdgeBrowser does not work at all despite WebView2 installed
In my Delphi 12.1 VCL Application in Windows 11 Pro 64-bit I need a browser to render remote web pages from the Internet. So I dropped a TEdgeBrowser on my form to test it:
PAS file:
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Winapi.WebView2, Winapi.ActiveX,
  Vcl.Edge;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    EdgeBrowser1: TEdgeBrowser;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EdgeBrowser1.Navigate('https://www.example.com');
end;

end.

DFM file:
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Margins.Left = 5
  Margins.Top = 5
  Margins.Right = 5
  Margins.Bottom = 5
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 664
  ClientWidth = 938
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -18
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  Position = poScreenCenter
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 144
  TextHeight = 25
  object EdgeBrowser1: TEdgeBrowser
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 938
    Height = 664
    Margins.Left = 5
    Margins.Top = 5
    Margins.Right = 5
    Margins.Bottom = 5
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 0
    AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount = True
    TargetCompatibleBrowserVersion = '117.0.2045.28'
    UserDataFolder = '%LOCALAPPDATA%\bds.exe.WebView2'
    ExplicitLeft = 480
    ExplicitTop = 360
    ExplicitWidth = 150
    ExplicitHeight = 60
  end
end

I went to the Microsoft website:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section
and downloaded: MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe
After running the Webview installer, it said:

When running my test application, it showed: Nothing!
What must I do to make this work?

Don't you need to put the web view DLL next to the EXE?

To me it's a mystery why it is so difficult to render hypertext content in a Win32 app these days. It used to be absolutely trivial when the old IE control was universally available (and which still powers the CHM viewer after almost 25 years!). Why do you need a PhD in the web view control these days?</off-topic rant>

@AndreasRejbrand Because Trident (aka "MSHTML") from MSIE isn't alive anymore - Edge uses Blink/Chromium nowadays. Back then things were done with HTML/CSS, but nowadays everything is bloated with JS. That aside I don't get why people insist on using MS's faulty Edge when they could use Chromium Embedded Framework = CEF4Delphi directly. Without any client installation.

@AndreasRejbrand, I have placed WebView2Loader.dll next to the exe. It did not work.

@user1580348 Did you choose the DLL matching the bitness of your app?

@AndreasRejbrand My app is 32-bit. The property dialog of the DLL does not tell whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit.

For a test, I cmpiled the app as 64-bit. No difference.

I downloaded the CEF4 Framework from Github. The demos don't work because they need  SEVERAL TONS of binaries. To figure out how to put all these things together, I would need several weeks of work and a doctorate in CEF4.

@user1580348 That's because you didn't read https://www.briskbard.com/index.php?lang=en&pageid=cef#introduction which also states: "You need to copy the CEF binaries to the CEF4Delphi/bin directory and you can download them using these links". It's pretty straight forward and, of course, you also need to copy the files to each .EXE of your other projects. They're big, but they never need any installation elsewhere. BTW: I used OldCEF4Delphi successfully even if its Chromium engine is years old.

@AmigoJack, I've used CEF4Delphi, but it does have a fair learning curve, although in my opinion the end result is better.  And you don't have to copy those files to each folder with the .exe; you can have them in a common folder (although I'm talking about on one's own computer; it's probably better to have them in the same folder as the .exe when installing your app on someone else's computer).

@user1580348 Try WebView4Delphi and run a demo. It includes the right DLLs and you should be able to initialize the browser.

Per Embarcadero's documentation:
Using TEdgeBrowser Component and Changes to the TWebBrowser Component
It is not enough to just install the WebView2 control. You also need to install the WebView2 SDK so that you can copy its WebView2Loader.dll file into your app's folder (or anywhere else on the OS search path).
You also need to configure the browser's UserDataFolder property before you navigate to any URL.
Also, you should assign an OnCreateWebViewCompleted event handler to detect failures in initializing the WebView2 control. If you don't, you need to use the TApplication(Events).OnException event instead to catch the failure.
